# Jenkins Pipeline create directories from a list

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have a parameterized Jenkins pipeline that is expecting a string comma-delimited list (for example, "eddie,chelsey,adam"). For each element in the list, I would like to create a directory (sounds pretty easy, right?)

Here is what I have:

```
def list = params.list
def listSplit = list.split()
pipeline {
   agent {
            any
        }
   stages {
      stage('Create a directory from each element in the list')  {
          steps {
                   for (def i = 0; i < $listSplit.size(); ii++) {
                        dir ("${it}") {
                            writeFile file:'dummy', text:''
                        }                        
                    }
         }
     }
  }
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
WorkflowScript: 17: Expected a step @ line 17, column 21.
                       for (def i = 0; i < $LOBList.size(); ii++) {
                       ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:327)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Is this declarative or scripted DSL?

Comment: This is declarative.

Comment: You need to wrap any code that has control flow or variables into a `script` step. There are many other errors in the code though.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code into a [script](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script) block like this:

```
   stages {
      stage('Create a directory from each element in the list')  {
          steps {
                script{ // THIS IS MISSING
                      for (def i = 0; i < $listSplit.size(); i++) {
                           // logic                      
                      }
                }
         }
   }
```